# Simple exercises to learn Netwire?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, arrows

[Haskell wiki > Netwire](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Netwire) has some good introductory material to Netwire, but now (as a hobbyist Haskeller) I'm interested in something more. What kinds of simple exercises would be beneficial in order to sharpen my arrow/netwire skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that I didn't get around to updating the wiki page yet.  I hope to extend it in the coming days.  For now the #haskell channel on Freenode is probably your best bet.